# Unit testing - Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object when using a HasDbFunction()

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I have added a HasDbFunction() into my modelBuilder to allow access to oracles LPad function like so:

```
modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(() => OracleDbFunctions.LPad(default, default, default));
```

The OracleDbFunction Class is:

```
public static class OracleDbFunctions
{
    [DbFunction(IsBuiltIn = true)]
    public static string LPad(this string text, int totalWidth, string padding)
          => throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

It all works perfectly fine and does what I expect. However, now I am trying to unit test all my apis call which use this function. I get the following error: "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object"

I have ensured all data my DbContextMock uses is populated so not sure why this error occurs. Would I have to somehow initialise my OracleDbFunction.LPad in my DbContextMock?

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? Which version?

Comment: [Testing EF Core Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/). There are several strategies for testing applications with EF Core. Which one do you use?

Comment: Also see [Mocking Entity Framework when Unit Testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/mocking-entity-framework-when-unit-testing-aspnet-web-api-2)

Comment: Yes I'm using entity framework core version 6. Do you mean testing strategy about if I'm trying to use production database or test doubles? I don't use the production data base, I create dummy data within the unit tests